# Linking WPF object to C# styling

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I'm using the `TreeList` control from DevExpress. I'm trying to color in the some cells based on their value. I got the code structure from [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5650). However, my c# function does not seem to be linked to my WPF object. How can I link it together so it handles the `TreeList.NodeCellStyle` event?

**Sample Code**

```
private void treeList1_NodeCellStyle(object sender, GetCustomNodeCellStyleEventArgs e) {
   // Modify the appearance settings used to paint the "Budget" column's cells
   // whose values are greater than 500,000.
   if (e.Column.FieldName != "Budget") return;
   if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Node.GetValue(e.Column.AbsoluteIndex)) > 500000) {
      e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(80, 255, 0, 255);
      e.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.White;
      e.Appearance.Font = new Font(e.Appearance.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
   }
}
```

**Sample WPF**

```
<dxt:TreeListControl Name="treeList">
    <dxt:TreeListControl.Columns>
        <dxt:TreeListColumn FieldName="ClientID" Header="Heirarchy"/>
        <dxt:TreeListColumn FieldName="InstrumentID" />
        <dxt:TreeListColumn FieldName="OrderID" />
        <dxt:TreeListColumn FieldName="Status" />
        <dxt:TreeListColumn FieldName="OpenPosition" />
        <dxt:TreeListColumn FieldName="ExecPosition" />
        <dxt:TreeListColumn FieldName="CumOpenPosition" />
        <dxt:TreeListColumn FieldName="CumExecPosition" />
        <dxt:TreeListColumn FieldName="TransactionTime" />
        <dxt:TreeListColumn FieldName="LogTime" />
    </dxt:TreeListControl.Columns>
    <dxt:TreeListControl.View>
        <dxt:TreeListView Name="treeListView1" AutoWidth="True"
                          KeyFieldName="ID" ParentFieldName="ParentID" />
    </dxt:TreeListControl.View>
</dxt:TreeListControl>
```

Comment: Did you tried this : <dxt:TreeListControl Name="treeList" NodeCellStyle="treeList1_NodeCellStyle" >

Comment: The link you posted to DevExpress links to the WinForms-Control not the WPF-Control. NodeCellStyle doesn't work on this!

Comment: @GreenEyedAndy that makes sense!! How can I color the cells in WPF?

Comment: See https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1630. It's for GridView but I think you can see how it works.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a [`Trigger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.trigger.aspx) (which you'd attach to a calculated property on your model)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Conditional Formatting](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument17386).
Here is example in `WPF`:

```xml
<dxt:TreeListControl.View>
    <dxt:TreeListView Name="treeListView1" AutoWidth="True"
                      KeyFieldName="ID" ParentFieldName="ParentID">
        <dxt:TreeListView.FormatConditions>
            <dxt:FormatCondition FieldName="Budget" Expression="[Budget] &gt; 500000">
                <dx:Format Foreground="White" Background="#50FF00FF" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </dxt:FormatCondition>
        </dxt:TreeListView.FormatConditions>
    </dxt:TreeListView>
</dxt:TreeListControl.View>
```

The same in `c#`:

```
treeListControl1.View.FormatConditions.Add(new FormatCondition()
{
    FieldName = "Budget",
    Expression = "Budget > 500000",
    Format = new Format()
    {
        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(80, 255, 0, 255)),
        Foreground = Brushes.White,
        FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold
    }
});
```